# Is there any more meaning to Ren's name?

Tags: nana

[image: Ren]

In 'Nana', Nana(the singer) has a tattoo of a lotus flower on her arm.

The lotus flower shares the same Kanji as 'Ren' , Nana's boyfriend.

Flowers are used quite a bit in symbolism in media, Is there any further significance to this choice of flower aside from the similar names?

Comment: i don't think there's any meaning to the name `ren`.  as you've noted, there is meaning in nana's tattoo, in that it refers to him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @j__m mentioned, There's probably no more meaning to the name 'Ren' than meets the eye, but reading into it, Lotus flowers can symbolize several things that could be linked to their relationship:

- The Egyptians believed the lotus was a symbol of Rebirth, Life and Death

> In the final chapters of the manga, Their relationship is cut short by Ren's sudden death

- Buddhism associates the flower with loyalty and faithfullness

> Even though they separate, Ren and Nana return to each other. Ren's lock necklace is a symbol of loyalty also.

- Also, Red lotus flowers can be a symbol of love and harmony

[Ref1](http://www.lotusflowermeaning.net) [Ref2](http://exotic-arts-gallery.com/pages/Lotus-Flower-Meaning.html)

Answer (score 1):

The name Ren also means lotus. Nana Komatsu in the dubbed version says, "Nana had a tattoo of a red lotus on her arm, a lotus also known as a Ren flower. At the time I had no idea what that tattoo meant to her"

It is obvious that the tattoo refers to him and is a response to the chain Nana put around Ren's neck as they joked about Ren being Sid Vicious and Nana being his Nancy.